# Adding sub-menu dynamically to FXML via JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I have made a GUI interface via `Scene Builder`. I want to add child node to my Menu dynamically.

The FXML code sample:

```
<MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCreateNew" text="New" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOpen" text="Open…" />
                        <Menu fx:id="openRecentTab" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOpenRecentAction" text="Open Recent">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="" />
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="" />
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="" />
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                        <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleFileClose" text="Close" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSave" text="Save" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSaveAs" text="Save As…" />
                        <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleQuit" text="Quit" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
```

I want to change or add new `<MenuItem>` to my `<Menu fx:id="openRecentTab" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOpenRecentAction" text="Open Recent">`

Thanks

Comment: Reference your menu as an FXML field in your controller, and then create a new MenuItem and do `openRecentTab.getItems().add(menuItem)`

Comment: how should I reference my menu as an FXML field in my controller? `thanks though` I am new to JavaFx and FXML

Comment: `@FXML private Menu openRecentTab;`
[the field has to have the same name as the Fx:ID of the control.]
Then you can do whatever you'd like with openRecentTab, such as adding menu items to it when a button is clicked for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have linked a controller with the FXML file, as you have defined onAction triggers in it. However in case you haven't.

1- Create a new java file that will act as the **controller** of the FXML and place it in the same package as the FXML file. Suppose you named that class **MyController**.

2- Link that Controller to your FXML. You can do that in scene builder this way:

[image]

3- In your Controller class add the following

```
public class MyController {

    @FXML private Menu openRecentTab;

    @FXML public void addMenuItem() {
        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 1");
        MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 2");    
        MenuItem menuItem3 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 3");

        // Add multiple items at once
        openRecentTab.getItems().addAll(menuItem1, menuItem2);
        // Add one item
        openRecentTab.getItems().add(menuItem3);
    }
}
```

4- You can set the **addMenuItem** method to be called when for example a certain button is clicked. To do that set the **onAction** attribute of the button you want to trigger adding a new Item in your fxml to `#<methodName>` or in this instance `#addMenuItem`

**Note:** If you don't want to add your menu items through a trigger, and instead you want to add them dynamically before the **stage(window)** of your program is shown. You can use the **initialize** method to do this. To do this make your MyController class `implements Initializable` in this way:

```
public class MyController implements Initializable{

    @FXML private Menu openRecentTab;

    // This method is called before the stage is shown
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 1");
        MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem("Menu Item 2");
        openRecentTab.getItems().addAll(menuItem1, menuItem2);
    }
}
```